# Set min max zoom on ArcGIS map after initialization

Tags: javascript, arcgis

When I switch from Basemap A to Basemap B, I'm currently removing Basemap A layer and adding Basemap B layer.  This doesn't work properly when Basemap B has different zoom levels (lods) than Basemap A.

Is there a way to change the zoom level of the map without creating a new map instance?  I'm having trouble finding the API for something like that.

If there's no way of doing this, is there a way to create a new map object and transfer over the layers of another map object?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Javascript? Silverlight? iOS?

Comment: Can you share some code that shows what you've tried so far? You shouldn't have to create a new map instance to switch from one layer to another when they have different levels of detail.

Comment: What version of the javascript API are you working with?

Comment: 3.7, the code is pretty simple right now.  We have a map object with a basemap layer of type `ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer`.  When we switch basemap layer, we call `removeLayer(oldLayer)` then `addLayer(newLayer, 0)`.  The map still has the lod/zoom for the old layer.

Comment: I'm just reading the API, trying a few things, no luck so far.